# multiple glBlendFunc for one object

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I need to draw textured quad. My texture has some alpha pixels. So I need to do `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Thats OK. But I need some other blending function on that quad (`glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);`) to achieve textures masking. How can I do it? Because if I set both glBlendFunc, one of them is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Blending is a framebuffer operation and can not be set per primitive. If you need to combine several texture layers on a single primitive, do this in a shader and emit a compound color/alpha that interacts in the right way with the choosen blending function. If you need different blending functions, you must do this using separate drawing calls.

Comment: So if I draw that texture with one type of blending to framebuffer, and later draw that framebuffer with other blending it should work?

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: Yes, but the effect obtained by **that** is easier obtained by using a shader.